Postapocalyptic sci-fi book with robot "Angels" suppressing human knowledge
I'm looking for a book title about a postapocalyptic world where the survivors live in isolated villages and knowledge and technological progress is suppressed by "Angels" that turn out to be robots.
There are some other remnants of the former high tech civilization like a device that provides food and most of these remnants are explained with religion instead of science. Some few know that these remnants are technology and exploit their knowledge for power.
One day an outsider comes to the protagonists village and the protagonist helps the outsider, eventually escaping the village together.
They find another village that they have to flee from as well. They are then followed by one of the Angels who is almost indestructible, but in the end they manage to destroy it and hike over a mountain to find a village they heard about where they might find a better life.
If I remember correctly books are pretty much banned maybe except for religious texts.
Some more advanced technology that humans use are guns, but they are rare.
There were no cars, computers or similar modern conveniences.

Sounds a bit like The Memory of Earth except that the angels are evolved birds (and I'm not certain if they showed up in the first book)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_Armageddon_Reef similarly has technology-forbidding angels, but the plot doesn't match.
